# Proving $\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)+5}+\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\gamma)+5}+\sqrt{\tan(\beta)\tan(\gamma)+5}\le4\sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=90^{\circ}$, then we have following inequality:
$$\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)+5}+\sqrt{\tan(\alpha)\tan(\gamma)+5}+\sqrt{\tan(\beta)\tan(\gamma)+5}\le4\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I believe you need $0 \leq \alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Comment: **Hint** reduce your condition to showing that if $a+b+c=1$, then $\sqrt{a+5}+\sqrt{b+5}+\sqrt{c+5}\le4\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @CalvinLin: You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the roots exist(As in Calvin Lin's comment). Elaborating on my comment, if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=90^\circ$ then

$$\alpha+\beta=90^\circ-\gamma$$
$$\implies\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=\tan(90^\circ-\gamma)=\cot\gamma$$
$$\implies\tan\alpha\tan\gamma+\tan\beta\tan\gamma+\tan\alpha\tan\beta=1$$
$$\iff\tan\alpha\tan\gamma+5+\tan\beta\tan\gamma+5+\tan\alpha\tan\beta+5=16$$
Let's rephrase our problem:
$$\text{Show }a+b+c=16\implies\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\le4\sqrt{3}$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: yes, thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you take $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \frac{\pi}{3}$, you will get $3\sqrt{8}\leq 4\sqrt{3}$ that is not true...

Comment: it should be $\frac{\pi}{6}$ not $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: $\pi/3+\pi/3+\pi/3\neq\pi/2$